# Publishing war file to artifactory using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

So, the below war file publishes the jar file and the war file. It publishes the war file because I have it specified under publications as "artifact(file('build/libs/new_file-1.0.war'))".

Question 1: Is there a way to publish war files without specifying full names ?

Question 2: Why is the jar file being published ? I am not even building it ?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://localhost/artifactory/plugins-release'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '3.1.1')
        }
        configurations {
            warLib {
                transitive=false
            }
        }
    }

    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'war'

    war {
        classpath configurations.warLib
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
                artifact(file('build/libs/new_file-1.0.war'))
                }
        }
    }

    artifactory {
        contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
        publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = ‘aaa'
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
                maven = true
            }

            defaults {
                publications('mavenJava')
                publishPom = false
            }
        }
        resolve {
            repository {
                repoKey = ‘aba'
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
                maven = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Question 3: Is there a way to pull specific libraries as part of dependencies into specific location ?

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'a', name: 'application_jar', version: '1.0'
    compile group: 'b', name: 'newlock', version:'1.0.0'
    testCompile group: 'unit', name: 'unit', version:'1.0'
}
```

From the above dependencies, I want to pull library **a** into different directory, lets say build/deps and all the other ones into the .gradle directory in $HOME.

Can somebody please help.

Comment: #3 is unrelated to #1 and #2, please post as a separate question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#2. The `publications{}` section defines what is published. The line `from components.java` adds the jar file. If you do not want to publish the jar, remove that line.

#1 To publish the war file generated by the war plugin, use `from components.web`